# Oracle Query, why double quotes around results, can I prevent them?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, double-quotes

Oracle Query, why double quotes around results, can I prevent them?
I am running a query to create a fix length file that I will send to a mainframe to be processed. The results have double quotes that I need to remove before sending the file. I need to prevent the quotes via the query if possible. Here is the query:

```
SELECT '00000000' || 
CAST(' ' AS CHAR(161)) || '95005000000000000000' || 
CAST(' ' AS CHAR(63)) ||
CAST(CONACCT.CONTACT_ID AS CHAR(24)) || 
CAST(CONACCT.LOCATION_CODE AS CHAR(6)) ||
CAST(CONACCT.ACCT_NUM AS CHAR(18)) || 
CONACCT.NAME_RELATIONSHIP ||
CONACCT.LEAD_CONTACT_IND || 
CONACCT.RESPONSIBLE_PARTY ||
CONACCT.CAS_ADDRESS_IND || 
CAST(CONACCT.EXT_SYS_ID AS CHAR(4)) || 
CONACCT.PREF_CURRENCY
FROM CACS.CONTACT_ACCOUNT CONACCT,
CACS.ACCOUNT ACCT
WHERE CONACCT.ACCT_NUM = ACCT.ACCT_NUM
```

And the results look like (I removed most of the data for brevity):
"00000000   95005000000000000000   ... USD"

I need the double quotes not to be in the results. Thanks.

Comment: Where is this query running, and how are the results being written to a file? That query doesn't include any double-quotes itself, so something else must be adding them - possibly at the point you write each returned line to the file. Showing the code that runs this might be useful.

Comment: This is ran using a scheduling / workflow software, ASG Zena. The Zena process runs the the query above. The process has a tab where I can enter the file path / name to write the output to. As I write this, I realize that Zena is most likely putting the quotes around the output. Thanks for your input.